# How insert PR info to file CHANGELOG.md in current repo on merge PR to master?

Tags: github, github-actions

I try create GitHub action for update `CHANGELOG.md` on merge PR to `master` branch.
But I don't know how get PR info (author and title) and add it to log file in repo, `action.yml`:

```
on pull_request_review:
  types:
    - submitted
  branches:
    - master
jobs:
  update-changelog:
    name: Update CHANGELOG.md
    if: ${{ github.event.review.state == 'approved' }}
    steps:
      - name: Get PR info
        run: ???
      - name: Add PR to log file
        run: ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to have an on-demand action which will scan the most recent PR already merged to master, and update `CHANGELOG.md`

That is what proposes [Changelog CI](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changelog-ci)

> Changelog CI uses python and GitHub API to generate changelog for a repository.
>
> - First, it tries to get the latest release from the repository (If available).
> - Then, it checks all the pull requests / commits merged after the last release using the GitHub API.
> - After that, it parses the data and generates the changelog.
> - Finally, It writes the generated changelog at the beginning of the CHANGELOG.md (or user-provided filename) file.

Comment: I'm found answers in Changelog CI.